# Passing an Object to Switch Case Javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanted to have a switch/case statement that accepts an object in Javascript.

The function looks like this.

```
const validate = (values) => { values is an object, can be accessed like so (values.bar, values.foo)
  const errors = {}

  switch(values) {
    case !values.bar || values.bar === '':
       errors.bar = 'Enter bar'
    case values.bar.length < 10: 
       errors.bar = 'Bar is too short'
    case !values.foo || values.foo === '':
       errors.foo = 'Enter foo'
    ...

    default: 
      return errors
  } 
}
```

This doesn't work and I have used an if/else statement instead, but I feel like a switch/case would be perfect for this kind of example. Thoughts?

Comment: That's not how `switch` works: [`switch (**expression**) {`...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Change

```
switch(values) {
```

To

```
switch(true) {
```

[`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) checks with [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()).

And use, if necessary some `break` if you do not want to fall through the switch cases (kudos to blex).

Comment: I do not undertand the purpose of 'switch statement'. I think that is better to use 'if/else'

Comment: Interesting, i missed the part where it strictly checks `expression` to the values in the `case` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch, Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: the idea behind switch is to lessen the amount of syntax you need, and exhaust all possible options of a type definition like an enum. Since JS is dynamic and there are no true enum types, plus you can just say `if(someVar)` instead of `if(someVar === true)` it doesn't quite make sense. I also find and break/brackets/semicolons, its a little clunky. Still, if you see code like this in typescript or something that's probably the intention.

Comment: thanks for including  `break`, that really helped

Answer (score 0):

You are using it like a function parameter which is unnecessary (and wrong). Since switch statements check that the value equals the case, you'll want to use:

```
switch(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const switchCase=(obj={},str='')=>obj[Object.keys(obj).find(ele=>ele.toString().split('|').includes(str.toString())) || 'default']


console.log(switchCase({
   default:'o',
  40:'ko',
  xyz:'hi',
  'yi|th' :'ho'
},'yi'))
```